# R.java not updating

Tags: java, android, eclipse, r.java-file

I am unable to build my app because `R.java` will not update the ids. I updated the id in `main.xml` but the old values remain. This obviously prevents it from building. Is there any way to fix this? Could I manually update `R.java` by renaming the variables and leaving the references untouched, or is this unsafe? There are no problems other than the 3 lines of code posted below and unused variable warnings.

**StopwatchAppActivity.java:**

```
pauseBtn = (Button)   findViewById(R.id.pause_btn);
resetBtn = (Button)   findViewById(R.id.reset_btn);
timeDisp = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.time_tv);
```

**main.xml:**

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/time_tv"
    ... />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/pause_btn"
    ... />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/reset_btn"
    ... />
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. Check all of your XML,
2. Project -> Clean,
3. Right click -> Fix Project Properties,
4. Repeat.
5. Maybe try restarting Eclipse

My panic list for R generation problems

Comment: So I did all this, cool. But I had a layout problem that was preventing recompile. All my layouts have warnings so I wasn't that turned off by this one. Turns out I had a layout with a capital name? If you go to your layouts folder, your problem layout can be identified by a warning icon to the left of the name

Answer (score 1):

Jest clean the project and  rebuild it still if you get the same problem delete the R.java from the eclipse it will recreated automatically with the new values.

Note: check R.java  package imported in your project. If it's android.R jest replace with 
your package name.R;

Answer (score 0):

When you make a Project/Clean it will not run properly if you have a resource with an error in its name, like for example an image with an upper case letter. Loot at the console error messages after the Clean.

Answer (score 0):

remove unwanted files from project and remove unwanted code from menifest file .
R.java will update automatically :)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. The only thing that finally solved it was deleting the id text that had been autogenerated by using the graphical layout. As soon as I manually typed the "@+id/... the .java file recognised it.